# When we set the font-size in px in CSS, which dimension of the text actually sets to that value?

Tags: css, font-size, typography

There were lots of articles about different measures in CSS, but actually I couldn't find any of them answering my question!

**when we set a font-size for example to 16px, which part of glyphs or characters will set to 16px ? (is it x-height, Cap-height or ... ) ?!**

**and how can i control over the height of my characters accurately in css ? (something like using ex unit, but for the whole height of the characters)**

Answer (score 2):

This completely depends on how the vector images were defined in the font.

When defining a font you have a "document", just like you would when using Adobe Illustrator or any other vector editing tool. The document would be 100% height. If the person building the font did not stretch the glyph to the height of the document it would never be as high at the defined size.

For text characters (typefaces) there are guides on how descenders, "g, y", capital height "A vs. a" and ascenders will appear etc., but not for glyphs. So there is no real point-of-measure.

Getting a glyph to size correctly is sometime a matter of trial and error. **Ideally the glyph should be the same height as a capital letter** (E) but sometimes glyphs are different sizes for a reason. For example, a trademark (™) is designed to be a superscript. It is smaller but is designed to be in proportion to the base font size.

For a more detailed look at how fonts are defined see: [Typeface Anatomy.](https://www.fontshop.com/glossary/)

Comment: That was a great answer, thanks :D
but let me extend my question a little bit. is there some kind of unit in CSS like em or ex that gives me control over the height of the as you said "document" of the font ?!

Answer (score 2):

The [`font-size`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/fonts.html#font-size-props) property sets the size of the font, which equals the height of the font, which does not equal any dimension of any character, except by accident. It is simply a reference quantity, which is typically sufficient to accommodate the entire vertical space occupied by characters, including descenders, ascenders, and common diacritic marks, but not any sequence of diacritic marks. Normally, “Q”, “É”, “þ”, and “Å” all fit inside the font height, which thus needs to be larger than the height of “E” and “A” for example. But this is not a law; in some fonts, e.g. “Å” extends above the top of the font height

Accidents include characters that have been defined to have dimensions that equal the font size. For example, EM SPACE can be expected to have width equal to the font size, but even this applies (according to the Unicode standard) just “nominally” and may vary by the condensation factor. (The EM DASH may have the width of one `em`, but this is not part of its definition, contrary to what its name suggests.)

The size of the font is surely larger than the x height and larger than the height of capital letters (partly because some capital letters have descenders). The very popular belief that the font size (the `em` unit) equals the width of “M” is patently false, as even the simplest check can prove.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. as i said to Diodeus, I want to take control of the height of my text in CSS mathematically and somehow i want this to be accurate (without using LESS or SCSS). is there anything else like ex unit that can help me achieve this ?